# How to update only one field in database using DAO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao

I have database with users(employees)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")

public class User {

public enum Role{
    USER,ADMIN
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String email;
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;
@Column(name = "company", nullable = false)
private String company;
private String title;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
private Role role = Role.USER;


public User() {
}

public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, String company, String title)

        {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.company = company;
    this.title = title;
     }
```

I have UserDao.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

And of course UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit-active-user/{email:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editActiveUserAgainGet(@PathVariable String email, Model model) {

    System.out.println(email.toString());
    User user = userDao.findByEmail(email);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "editUser";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUserAgain(@ModelAttribute User user) {

    userDao.save(user);

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

In jsp file named editUser I have form which contains e.g.:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">Title:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input required value="${user.title}" name="title" type="text" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your job title" autofocus>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

according to each user's attribute **without password**.

During update of attributes all of them are saved again (even some of them haven't been changed) but password is NULL because it wasn't in JSP form.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Question is how to update all of the fields except password field. Password field cannot be overwriten.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update let's say only one field, then you can write another method with `@Query` and `@Modifying` annotations in your repository, e.g.:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update user u set u.email = ?1 where u.id = ?2")
int setEmail(String email, Long id);
```

Here's the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need pass in hibernate dynamic-update=true. For details you can read following https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/

**UPDATE**

```
@Column(updatable="false")
```

If you pass updatable false it's would never be used in updates, only in insert.